# Google analytics Event tracking with an onclick=$('link')

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to add event tracking to my two buttons, but my button code looks like the following. I'm popping the user down to the section they clicked and hiding the other button's section:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="$('#order-form').show();$('#digital-download').hide();location.href='#Print'">
                                    Order Print
                                    Version
                                </button>
```

Anyone know how would I add the GA tracking code?

```html
// Form Tracking for Google Analytics 
$('.form-track').click(function(e){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Completions', 'Form_'+$(this).attr('title')+'_'+location.href]);  });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the _gaq code to the onclick for your button?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nyuen. Sort of, but I'm not really sure where to add it. Everything I've tried breaks the link.

Comment: Are you able to share your site?

Comment: Sure!http://marketing.pacificlife.com/sample/PacificPrimeTerm-V2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this, adding the following code to your buttons:

```
$('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg').click(function(e){
   ga('send','event','your_category', 'your_action',$(this).text().trim());
})
```

When the button is clicked, it will send the event with your specified category, action, and the button text as the label. Note that you are using UA, so the event tracking syntax in your example is incorrect.